# Passing the result of click event to invoking function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a function that is creating a 'confirm or cancel' dialog dynamically and binding click events to the OK and Cancel links.

```
function confirmOrCancelDialog() {
    //already created $dialog to popup on screen

    $dialog.find('a.confirm').click(function() {
        //close dialog
        return true;
    });

    $dialog.find('a.cancel').click(function() {
        //close dialog
        return false;
    });

}
```

Then, I am invoking the creation of this dialog from another function.  I want to pass the result of the interaction to the invoking function.

```
function performAction() {
    var clickResult = confirmOrCancelDialog();

    if (clickResult === true) {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Any guidance on how to do this would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Impossible, it is an asynchronous event

Comment: Well then, some way to structure it so that it is synchronous.

Comment: You can use a deferred object.

Comment: Just use a callback, or call out of the click function. The click could occur a very long time in the future and it would make no sense to block while waiting (which doesn't happen, the function will just complete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function confirmOrCancelDialog(someStuff) {
    //already created $dialog to popup on screen

    $dialog.find('a.confirm').click(function() {
        //close dialog
        someStuff(true);
        return true;
    });

    $dialog.find('a.cancel').click(function() {
        //close dialog
        someStuff(false);
        return false;
    });

}
function performAction() {
    confirmOrCancelDialog(function(clickResult){
        if (clickResult === true) {
            //do some stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This pattern is PERFECT.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an on click event to all anchors within the dialog object, and then check to see if the clicked anchor has the confirm class (or cancel, either one) and return accordingly:

```
$('.dialog a').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('confirm')) { return true; }

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Would have done it in a similar fashion if I had any control over it...  Thanks for your input sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function confirmOrCancelDialog(callback) {
  //already created $dialog to popup on screen
  $dialog.find('a.confirm').click(function() {
    //close dialog
    callback(true);
  });

  $dialog.find('a.cancel').click(function() {
    //close dialog
    callback(false);
  });
}

function performAction() {
  confirmOrCancelDialog(function(clickResult){
    if (clickResult === true) {
      //do some stuff
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't remember offhand if `callback` will still be in scope when it is called from within the click handlers. If you get a `callback is undefined` error, post a comment (even better, a jsfiddle) and I'll modify this to use a closure to save the `callback` reference.

Comment: Ha sorry @user1990577 I promise I didn't intentionally copy your answer <3

Comment: (why can't I post short comments...) @Plato ;)